# Play framework scala POST and Future

Tags: scala, playframework, future, blocking

I have this action in my controller

```
def doRegister = Action { implicit request =>
    Future {
      Thread.sleep(5000)
    }
    Ok("")
  }
```

This is the route

`POST /api/checkout/register  controllers.shop.checkout.CheckoutAuthController.doRegister`

I want to return the Ok result, without waiting for the Future.

It works with a GET requests (returns instantly), but not with POST. The timeout applies and the javascript vuejs project that make the call, has to wait.

Comment: Is your actual poc implementation `Thread.sleep` or its just a stub for this question ?

Comment: According to your current implementation, `Ok` response will be returned immediately without waiting `Future` complete, because you are not using `Action.async` and just `Action.apply` which accepts `Response` type not `Future[Response]`. Please, provide more details, Why it does not work for POST request? Thanks

Comment: But after 3-4 requests (depending on number of cpu cores), all your threads will be blocked. And the next request will not be processed till one of those threads becomes available.

Comment: Yeah, you would have to have a separate `ExecutionContext` just for the `Future`s that you don't wait for. And if you are flooded with requests then this executor might not keep up.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh My implementation is a service that sends mail, but the problem is the same

Comment: @IvanKurchenko I thought so, but that is not the case in real life (only with a GET request)

Comment: just wondering what control you have in case future will fail?

Comment: @Pavel this is a mail that is sent in background. 
I log the error, but I dont feedback the user about that.

Comment: I would rather send this user message to designated persistent actor which will provide guaranty that message will be eventually emailed etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Mateusz's advice, offload blocking calls to a [separate thread pool](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ThreadPools#Using-other-thread-pools), for example

```
val ecForBlockingTasks = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5))

def doRegister = Action { implicit request =>
  Future {
    Thread.sleep(5000)
  }(ecForBlockingTasks)

  Ok("")
}
```

Make sure you create the thread pool only **once** at app launch, otherwise you might end up with a resource leak.

Comment: I moved the blocking code in a service, how can I ensure the separate ExecutionContext is instantiated once, when it is in a service ?

Comment: You could define it in your config - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ThreadPools#Using-other-thread-pools